# Show File Path in Access 2010 Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form in Access 2010 that allows the user to find an Excel file and map it so that it can easily be accessed from another form. The simplest way to explain it, I think, is with a picture:

[image: Mapping Form]

The form has this `On Load` event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String
Dim sPath As String
Set db = CurrentDb

On Error GoTo Error_Handler

sPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path

sSQL = "Select Setting from tblBackendFiles where Code = 'SourceVerification'"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
Me.tVerificationPath = Nz(rs!Setting, "")
If Len(Me.tVerificationPath) = 0 Then
    Me.tExcelPath = sPath
End If
Me.cmdAcceptPath.SetFocus
rs.Close

GoTo exit_sub

Error_Handler:
MsgBox Err.number & ": " & Err.Description, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Error!"

exit_sub:
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

What I want is to have the current path of the Excel file displayed in the textbox, which is currently unbound. I've looked around online but I'm having a hard time finding how to actually get the path to show up.

What would be the best way to do this? I'd prefer to do it without VBA if at all possible, but I'm not 100% opposed to it.

Comment: What's to stop you just setting the textbox to the path in your `Form_Load` code?  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Should Application.CurrentProject.Path be Application.CurrentDB.Path? Over-and-above this, I think you need to provide the structure and some example content of tblBackendFiles, in order for someone to help.

Comment: So does the path come from the `Setting` field in your `tblBackendFiles` table? Is the textbox on your pictured subform called `tVerificationPath`? Is the `load` event you've posted taken from the main form or the subform? If it's the main form, then any controls that are on the subform can't be referenced `Me.myControlName`; you'd need to something like `Me!mySubFormName.Form!myControlName`.

Comment: @MattHall The path is from `tblBackendfiles`, and the textbox is called `tVerificationPath`. I made a mistake in the question; this is a main form, not a subform.

Comment: I assume your it's your `Me.tVerificationPath = Nz(rs!Setting, "")` line that's not working as you expect? If that's the case have you tried `Debug.Print rs!setting` and seeing what gets printed to the immediate window? If `setting`'s null, then your line will just send a zero-length string to your text box. Also, when you apply the filter `WHERE Code = 'SourceVerification'` to your `tblBackendfiles` table, will this definitely return one record? Does it return any records at all? Test the sql in your `sSQL` string in query design to see if it runs ok and returns the result you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this many times.  You will have to create a form.  On that form, place a textbox called "tbFile", another called "tbFileName" (which is invisible) and a button called "bBrowse".

Then, behind your form, put this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub bBrowse_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_bBrowse_Click

    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim lngFlags As Long
    Dim varFileName As Variant

    Me.tbHidden.SetFocus

'   strFilter = "Access (*.mdb)" & vbNullChar & "*.mdb" _
'    & vbNullChar & "All Files (*.*)" & vbNullChar & "*.*"
'    strFilter = "Access Files (*.mdb)" & vbNullChar & "*.mdb*"
    strFilter = "All Files (*.*)" & vbNullChar & "*.*"

    lngFlags = tscFNPathMustExist Or tscFNFileMustExist Or tscFNHideReadOnly

    varFileName = tsGetFileFromUser( _
    fOpenFile:=True, _
    strFilter:=strFilter, _
    rlngflags:=lngFlags, _
    strInitialDir:="C:\Windows\", _
    strDialogTitle:="Find File (Select The File And Click The Open Button)")
    'remove the strInitialDir:="C:\Windows\", _ line if you do not want the Browser to open at a specific location

    If IsNull(varFileName) Or varFileName = "" Then
        Debug.Print "User pressed 'Cancel'."
        Beep
        MsgBox "File selection was canceled.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'Debug.Print varFileName
        tbFile = varFileName
    End If

    Call ParseFileName

Exit_bBrowse_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_bBrowse_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_bBrowse_Click

End Sub

Private Function ParseFileName()
On Error GoTo Err_ParseFileName

    Dim sFullName As String
    Dim sFilePathOnly As String
    Dim sDrive As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sLocation As String
    Dim sFileName As String

    sFullName = tbFile.Value

    ' Find the final "\" in the path.
    sPath = sFullName

    Do While Right$(sPath, 1) <> "\"
    sPath = Left$(sPath, Len(sPath) - 1)
    Loop

    ' Find the Drive.
    sDrive = Left$(sFullName, InStr(sFullName, ":") + 1)
    'tbDrive = sDrive

    ' Find the Location.
    sLocation = Mid$(sPath, Len(sDrive) - 2)
    'tbLocation = sLocation

    ' Find the Path.
    sPath = Mid$(sPath, Len(sDrive) + 1)
    'tbPath = sPath

    ' Find the file name.
    sFileName = Mid$(sFullName, Len(sPath) + 4)
    tbFileName = sFileName

Exit_ParseFileName:
    Exit Function

Err_ParseFileName:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_ParseFileName

End Function
```

Then, create a new Module and paste this into it:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function ts_apiGetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
 Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (tsFN As tsFileName) As Boolean

Private Declare Function ts_apiGetSaveFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
 Alias "GetSaveFileNameA" (tsFN As tsFileName) As Boolean

Private Declare Function CommDlgExtendedError Lib "comdlg32.dll" () As Long

Private Type tsFileName
   lStructSize As Long
   hwndOwner As Long
   hInstance As Long
   strFilter As String
   strCustomFilter As String
   nMaxCustFilter As Long
   nFilterIndex As Long
   strFile As String
   nMaxFile As Long
   strFileTitle As String
   nMaxFileTitle As Long
   strInitialDir As String
   strTitle As String
   flags As Long
   nFileOffset As Integer
   nFileExtension As Integer
   strDefExt As String
   lCustData As Long
   lpfnHook As Long
   lpTemplateName As String
End Type

' Flag Constants
Public Const tscFNAllowMultiSelect = &H200
Public Const tscFNCreatePrompt = &H2000
Public Const tscFNExplorer = &H80000
Public Const tscFNExtensionDifferent = &H400
Public Const tscFNFileMustExist = &H1000
Public Const tscFNPathMustExist = &H800
Public Const tscFNNoValidate = &H100
Public Const tscFNHelpButton = &H10
Public Const tscFNHideReadOnly = &H4
Public Const tscFNLongNames = &H200000
Public Const tscFNNoLongNames = &H40000
Public Const tscFNNoChangeDir = &H8
Public Const tscFNReadOnly = &H1
Public Const tscFNOverwritePrompt = &H2
Public Const tscFNShareAware = &H4000
Public Const tscFNNoReadOnlyReturn = &H8000
Public Const tscFNNoDereferenceLinks = &H100000

Public Function tsGetFileFromUser( _
    Optional ByRef rlngflags As Long = 0&, _
    Optional ByVal strInitialDir As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal strFilter As String = "All Files (*.*)" & vbNullChar & "*.*", _
    Optional ByVal lngFilterIndex As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal strDefaultExt As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal strFileName As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal strDialogTitle As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal fOpenFile As Boolean = True) As Variant
On Error GoTo tsGetFileFromUser_Err

    Dim tsFN As tsFileName
    Dim strFileTitle As String
    Dim fResult As Boolean

    ' Allocate string space for the returned strings.
    strFileName = Left(strFileName & String(256, 0), 256)
    strFileTitle = String(256, 0)

    ' Set up the data structure before you call the function
    With tsFN
        .lStructSize = Len(tsFN)
        .hwndOwner = Application.hWndAccessApp
        .strFilter = strFilter
        .nFilterIndex = lngFilterIndex
        .strFile = strFileName
        .nMaxFile = Len(strFileName)
        .strFileTitle = strFileTitle
        .nMaxFileTitle = Len(strFileTitle)
        .strTitle = strDialogTitle
        .flags = rlngflags
        .strDefExt = strDefaultExt
        .strInitialDir = strInitialDir
        .hInstance = 0
        .strCustomFilter = String(255, 0)
        .nMaxCustFilter = 255
        .lpfnHook = 0
    End With

    ' Call the function in the windows API
    If fOpenFile Then
        fResult = ts_apiGetOpenFileName(tsFN)
    Else
        fResult = ts_apiGetSaveFileName(tsFN)
    End If

    ' If the function call was successful, return the FileName chosen
    ' by the user.  Otherwise return null.  Note, the CancelError property
    ' used by the ActiveX Common Dialog control is not needed.  If the
    ' user presses Cancel, this function will return Null.
    If fResult Then
        rlngflags = tsFN.flags
        tsGetFileFromUser = tsTrimNull(tsFN.strFile)
    Else
        tsGetFileFromUser = Null
    End If

tsGetFileFromUser_End:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

tsGetFileFromUser_Err:
    Beep
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error: " & Err.Number _
    & " in function basBrowseFiles.tsGetFileFromUser"
    Resume tsGetFileFromUser_End

End Function

' Trim Nulls from a string returned by an API call.
Private Function tsTrimNull(ByVal strItem As String) As String
On Error GoTo tsTrimNull_Err
    Dim I As Integer

    I = InStr(strItem, vbNullChar)
    If I > 0 Then
        tsTrimNull = Left(strItem, I - 1)
    Else
        tsTrimNull = strItem
    End If

tsTrimNull_End:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

tsTrimNull_Err:
    Beep
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error: " & Err.Number _
    & " in function basBrowseFiles.tsTrimNull"
    Resume tsTrimNull_End

End Function

Public Sub tsGetFileFromUserTest()
On Error GoTo tsGetFileFromUserTest_Err

    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim lngFlags As Long
    Dim varFileName As Variant

'   strFilter = "Access (*.mdb)" & vbNullChar & "*.mdb" _
'    & vbNullChar & "All Files (*.*)" & vbNullChar & "*.*"
    strFilter = "All Files (*.*)" & vbNullChar & "*.*"

    lngFlags = tscFNPathMustExist Or tscFNFileMustExist Or tscFNHideReadOnly

    varFileName = tsGetFileFromUser( _
    fOpenFile:=True, _
    strFilter:=strFilter, _
    rlngflags:=lngFlags, _
    strDialogTitle:="GetFileFromUser Test (Please choose a file)")

    If IsNull(varFileName) Then
        Debug.Print "User pressed 'Cancel'."
    Else
        Debug.Print varFileName
        'Forms![Form1]![Text1] = varFileName
    End If

    If varFileName <> "" Then MsgBox "You selected the '" & varFileName & "' file.", vbInformation

tsGetFileFromUserTest_End:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

tsGetFileFromUserTest_Err:
    Beep
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error: " & Err.Number _
     & " in sub basBrowseFiles.tsGetFileFromUserTest"
    Resume tsGetFileFromUserTest_End

End Sub
```

VOILA!  Easy as that.  ;o)